# SQL Query optimization Statistics

Tags: sql, performance

I was wondering if someone can give me a query to get the result.

Initial Table:

```
ID  Year  Quantity
```

Result Table:

```
ID  2009_Quantity    2010_Quantity     2011_Quantity ...
```

What I did now was:

```
Select ID 
, (select sum(Id.Quantity) from Initial_Database id where id.Year = 2009)
, (select sum(Id.Quantity) from Initial_Database id where id.Year = 2010)
from Initial_Database i
Group BY ID
```

But this is taking hours for millions of records, and this is nog an option.

I also tried:

```
Select ID 
, CASE WHEN i.Year = 2009 THEN  sum(Id.Quantity) ELSE 0 END
, CASE WHEN i.Year = 2010 THEN  sum(Id.Quantity) ELSE 0 END
from Initial_Database i
Group BY ID
```

Faster, But this gives me 2 lines which I don't want.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server SUM function can be used like `SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Year)`

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I haven't used OVER and PARTITION BY before, i'm not really a DBA'er. So I don't really know how to.

Comment: Try for example; `SELECT DISTINCT Year, SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) FROM Initial_Database` to see how it functions. The OVER () functions can help a lot in many situations to avoid sub queries, and maybe also for you in this. (I do think they're sql server specific though, but I'm sure other flavors have similar functions)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen This indeed gives me a sum for each year. But in rows, I would still have to translate them to columns.
2010    100 -
2011    50 -
2012    70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Select ID 
, SUM(CASE WHEN i.Year = 2009 THEN Id.Quantity ELSE 0 END)
, SUM(CASE WHEN i.Year = 2010 THEN Id.Quantity ELSE 0 END)
from Initial_Database i
Group BY ID
```

Comment: I'm so angry @ my self now for not trying that... It seems to work, i'll try the insert, if it works i'll mark the answer.